# Uploading phonegap iOS application to app store not working

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7, app-store

I'm trying to upload phonegap application to Apple app store. I have validated my application successfully, but when i try to upload to app store for review it show me the attached screen and never uploaded. I have left it more than 8 hours hoping it will finish but in vain.[image: phonegap iOS application not uploading to apple app store]

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue a couple of times and this issue is not necessarily to do with a phonegap app.

There are two solutions

1. Upgrade to xcode 6 and try again.
2. Archive and Export .ipa of the project.
   Open File-> Developer Tools->Application Loader and upload the binary (.ipa) from here.